# Google Analytics: filter to show full URI in reports, but only for subdomain

Tags: google-analytics

I need to track a subdomain under an existing property that is already tracking my domain. From the user's perspective they look like one site and I need to see the flow of traffic between them, so they should ideally be under the same property.

I'm trying to configure things so that I can tell the difference between data for the domain and subdomain in my reports. I've done some research and most of the instructions that I've found give the solution of a filter to show the full path of all URIs in your reports. But that would mean that the new data for the main domain no longer matches up with historical data: it would make it more difficult to compare to the past and would require me to update all my destination goals.

I would like to only show the full URI for the subdomain, so the data for my main domain stays consistent. I'm sure that adding on a subdomain to an established website is a pretty common scenario and I'm not the only person who has this issue.

I did find one set of instructions for showing the full hostname for just one subdomain: http://www.ericmobley.net/guide-to-tracking-multiple-subdomains-in-google-analytics/

I set up the advanced filter as he specified, with my subdomain in brackets as the expression in the hostname field (screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5zc6c.png). When I checked my reports to test this, the real-time reports were showing the full path of traffic to the subdomain but not the main domain. The subdomain URIs were displaying in brackets. However, in the Behaviour reports the hostname wasn't showing up for either site and there was no distinction between traffic to the domain and subdomain.

What am I doing wrong here? Is it possible to create a filter that does what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Advanced filter fields use regex, so field A should look like this

```
(support\.whatever\.org\.au)
```

Note that this filter includes ONLY the support sub domain.